# What is (lambda lambda lambda)?

Tags: racket

My friend shows this to me, and I am really curious why it works like this. I at first thought that it's gonna be a syntax error, but it doesn't... Here're some of my experiments:

```
> (lambda lambda lambda)
#<procedure>
> ((lambda lambda lambda))
'()
> ((lambda lambda lambda) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (lambda lambda foo)
#<procedure>
> ((lambda lambda foo))
foo: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (lambda lambda 1 2 3 4 5)
#<procedure>
> ((lambda lambda 1 2 3 4 5))
5
> (lambda foo lambda)
. lambda: bad syntax in: lambda
> (lambda 1 2 3)
. lambda: bad argument sequence in: 1
> ((lambda) 1 2 3)
. lambda: bad syntax in: (lambda)
```

So it seems:

1. In `lambda`, `lambda` could be arg-ids?
2. In `lambda`, `lambda` could be a list constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ohhh I got it. `lambda` could be shadowed!

```
> ((lambda (lambda) (+ 1 lambda)) 7)
8
```

Also, the syntax given at https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html is not entirely correct because at `arg-ids` position, an identifier could be there! This will bind the list of arguments with the identifier:

```
> ((lambda foo foo) 1 2 3 4)
'(1 2 3 4)
```

These explain it!

Comment: Thx :) In fact, the link I posted mentioned `rest-id` as well in 4.4.1, but I didn't see it!

Comment: Yes. However, there is one more strange case that this doesn't explain. `(lambda lambda foo)` = `#<procedure>`. And that's because this is in a REPL, where you can do `(define (f x) foo)` and then define foo later, so that for instance mutual recursion works. But for these things, you really should put them in a file, because that's what will show their true behavior. In a file by itself, `(lambda lambda foo)` will be an error, as it should.